# Grafana: how to overwrite values in one table with value mapping retrieved from another table

Tags: grafana

I have two tables as below. 1st table contain descriptions of all statuses. How to overwrite column `status_id` on right table with `name` from left table based on `id`?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: fixed list of mappings

When the status are fixed and a low number, I would recommend to use [value mapping](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/format-data/about-value-mapping/).

Make sure not to apply it to the whole table, but instead to use an [override](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels/override-field-values/add-a-field-override/) for the field `status_id` in your table.

#### Option 2: variable list of mappings

In case the status change or new ones are added, I would suggest a workaround as follows (since I don't use PostgreSQL, I show SQL statements from Google BigQuery standard SQL, please adjust for your usecase):

Create a [query variable](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/variable-types/add-query-variable/): query the table with the mappings (the description of the status) and by using concatenation, create the `WHEN ... THEN ...` part of a case statement. Example:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('WHEN "', id, '" THEN "', name, '" ')
FROM ID_TABLE
```

This will give you rows like this: `WHEN "1" THEN "OK"`. Then you have to concat/aggregate those rows to a single string.

Then use the variable in the query for your final table like in this example:

```sql
SELECT
  CASE status_id
    ${QUERY_VARIABLE}
  ELSE "UNKNOWN STATUS"
  END AS status_id,
  ...
FROM YOUR_DATA_TABLE
```

Comment: It looks interesting, but unfortunately I need do it without value mapping. Statuses table may be changed or extended, so I must take care about it.

Comment: I understand. I just edited my answer to be applicable to that usecase too.

Comment: Thank You, I prepare my own solution based on Your 2nd option!